# Ambiguous use of resignFirstResponder()

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Hi I have this function :

```
extension UIApplication
{
    func resignFirstResponder()
 {sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil) }
}
```

And when I try to use it like this:

```
UIApplication.shared.resignFirstResponder()
```

I got this :

> Ambiguous use of 'resignFirstResponder()'

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: `UIApplication` has nothing to do with SwiftUI. That's part of UIKit, not SwiftUI, so I've fixed the tags on your question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `UIApplication` already has a `resignFirstResponder() -> Bool` method, so when you try to overload that method with another variant with a `Void` return type, the compiler cannot figure out which version you are trying to call.

You can resolve this by explicitly telling the compiler to expect a `Void` return, but that results in an unused return value, so I'd rather suggest renaming your method.

```
let void: Void = UIApplication.shared.resignFirstResponder()
```

Renamed version:

```
extension UIApplication {
    func resignFirstResponderNoReturn() {
        sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

UIApplication.shared.resignFirstResponderNoReturn()
```